# Fix Linux home default permissions

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

I broke my home directory and file permissions by moving to and from drives etc. How do I restore default permissions on my home directory?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315799/default-permissions-on-linux-home-directorys

Answer (score 2):

You could run as root these commands, where `user` is the user's name:

```
sudo chown -R user /home/user
```

And if necessary:

```
find /home/user -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
find /home/user -type d -exec chmod 0775 {} \;
```

The later will destroy permissions such as execute, which you will need
to add manually as required. Presumably, these permissions were already
lost after being copied to external filesystems that didn't support them.

Comment: running the chmods above might not work as you run the first command with sudo and if the files are not owned or accessible by user "user" if we suppose the use "user" is logged in. and no only it will not restore execute access, it will even destroy it - it will REMOVE the execute bit from all files. and we don't know what is broken. so maybe a plain `sudo chown -R user /home/user` will fix the OP's issue.

Comment: @Zina: Right - I modified my answer.